# Why material is not showing on some objects?

Tags: materials

I'm doing simple houses and adding the materials to them.[image] Added base material, and second one for the roof. On some houses, second material isn't showing unless I isolate the selected object. [image] As you can see, nodes are checked and faces are assigned to the materials. My file: https://workupload.com/file/FQ8g7gXuPH7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, you have overlapping meshes, just grab (<kbd>L</kbd>) and delete the bad mesh (or select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*):

[image]